# Why does internal instance become null

Tags: c#

I am trying to figure out why the assigner (myC.myself) become null after the line is compiled?
Thanks in advance.

```
namespace AequalsBequalsC
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A myA = new A();
        A myB = new A();
        myB.a = 8;
        A myC = new A();
        myC.a = 9;

        myC.myself = myA;
        myC = myC.myself;

        Console.WriteLine("myA.a is {0}, myB.a is {1}, myC.a is {2}", myA.a,myB.a, myC.a);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
  public class A
  {
    public int a = 4;
    public A myself;
  }
}
```

Comment: You assigned myA to myC.myself, then assigned myC.myself to myC. myA never set its own .myself, so that's what myC.myself is now null.

Comment: You also asked this question on the wrong site.

Answer (score 2):

It never becomes `null`. **It always was null.** When you create new instances of your class A, myself `variable` is never assigned, and thus is `null`.

When you assign `myC.myself` the `myA` value, and then subsequently the same `myA` value to `myC`, `myC` is no longer the third object you created, but the first one, which never had `myself` set in the first place.

Now if you did something like this(which I highly don't recommend!), it would not be null:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A myA = new A();
            A myB = new A();
            myB.a = 8;
            A myC = new A();
            myC.a = 9;

            myC.myself = myA;
            myC = myC.myself;

            Console.WriteLine("myA.a is {0}, myB.a is {1}, myC.a is {2}", myA.a, myB.a, myC.a);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class A
    {
        public int a = 4;
        public A myself;

        public A()
        {
            this.myself = this;
        }
    }
```